# Git failed with a fatal error. error: open("testdb/testdb.jfm"): Permission denied fatal: Unable to process path testdb/testdb.jfm

Tags: git, gitignore

I am facing an issue when I want to commit db changes to git. 
I got the following error:

> Git failed with a fatal error. error: open("testdb/testdb.jfm"):
>   Permission denied fatal: Unable to process path testdb/testdb.jfm

I have added `*.jfm` extenstion in gitignore file under `#User-specific files` tag 
but issue remain the same.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact git command and its output?
What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. 
I have fixed this issue by manually deleting testdb/testdb.jfm file from git server and then taken the latest to merge the code.

Answer (score 1):

> I have added *.jfm extenstion in gitignore file

Yes, but you also need to do:

```
git rm --cached *.jfm
```

That way, if those files were already tracked, they won't anymore, and the .gitignore will apply.

> I have fixed this issue by manually deleting `testdb/testdb.jfm` file from git server

That will work too: the pull will report that deletion locally.